# ui-router with multiple views on an abstract parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a `route` hierarchy with `ui-router`, and I am having issues.

I have three layers of templates: guest template, user template, admin template. So my `index.html` page is:

```
<html>
<head><!-- All common JS/CSS files such as Foundation and AngularJS --></head>
<body>
    <!-- Some common directive such as <reveal></reveal> used for dialog/popin pages -->
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, for each of my layers, I have another template. For instance, for `guest` I have:

**guest.html**

```
<nav><!-- The navigation for guest page --></nav>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

and for `user` it is slightly more complicated:

**user.html**

```
<nav><!-- The navigation for user page --></nav>
<ui-view="left"></ui-view>
<ui-view="main"></ui-view>
<ui-view="right"></ui-view>
```

Now, my state for `guest` is quite simple:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('guest', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'path/to/guest.html' 
    })
    .state('guest.login', {
        url: '/login/',
        template: '<login></login>'
    });
```

Problem rises with `user`. Just like above, I create an `abstract` state that adds the `user.html` to the template and gives me access to the 3 views. Normally, if I then extend the state, I can write to the three states as

```
.state('user.home', {
    url: '/home/',
    views: {
        'left':  { template: 'Left template' },
        'main':  { template: 'Main template' },
        'right': { template: 'Right template'}
    }
});
```

The problem is that I want to define another abstract here, called `user.schedule`, and these abstract state has a few children. When I do define this state, I still want to have access to the three views I had originally created in the `user.html`. However, since this is an abstract class, I need to define the templates for it.

I cannot figure out how to proceed with this abstract class. What I "thought" I should do was:

```
.state('user.schedule', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'left':  { template: '<ui-view></ui-view>' },
        'main':  { template: '<ui-view></ui-view>' },
        'right': { template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'}
    }
})
.state('user.schedule.view', {
    url: '/schedule/:day/:month/:year',
    views: {
        'left':  { template: 'This should work?' },
        'main':  { template: 'But it does not' },
        'right': { template: 'I even tried giving the ui above a name and calling them here'}
    }
})
```

What can I do?

Comment: "When I do define this state, I still want to have access to the three views I had originally created in the user.html."  Do you mean you want those views to be visible alongside your `user.schedule` views?

Comment: It's been a while since this question was asked, but I might be facing the exact same problem and not quite figuring out why the answer here is not working for me. Is it to much to ask to you to provide a plunker of this or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the left/main/right viewports you defined in `user.html` are only available to immediate children of the `user` abstract state.  It would then follow that the views you declare in your `user.schedule.view` state must correspond to named viewports in the `user.schedule` template.

Try naming the viewports in your `user.schedule` templates `left`,`main`,and `right`.  It's possible that there may be a name collision but hey, it's worth a shot.

ie. Change this:

```
.state('user.schedule', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'left':  { template: '<ui-view></ui-view>' },
        'main':  { template: '<ui-view></ui-view>' },
        'right': { template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'}
    }
})
.state('user.schedule.view', {
    url: '/schedule/:day/:month/:year',
    views: {
        'left':  { template: 'This should work?' },
        'main':  { template: 'But it does not' },
        'right': { template: 'I even tried giving the ui above a name and calling them here'}
    }
})
```

to this:

```
.state('user.schedule', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'left':  { template: '<ui-view="left"></ui-view>' },
        'main':  { template: '<ui-view="main"></ui-view>' },
        'right': { template: '<ui-view="right"></ui-view>'}
    }
})
.state('user.schedule.view', {
    url: '/schedule/:day/:month/:year',
    views: {
        'left':  { template: 'This should work?' },
        'main':  { template: 'But it does not' },
        'right': { template: 'I even tried giving the ui above a name and calling them here'}
    }
})
```

Also, I'm not sure that this is proper form:

`<ui-view="name"></ui-view>`

I *am* sure that this is proper form ([per the docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive%3aui-view)):

`<ui-view ui-view="name"></ui-view>`

or

`<div ui-view="name"></div>`