# How can i show parent template and child template using state providers

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I want to have single parent view and partial child views in a page i am using state providers.

AngularJs code:

```
           state('packs', {
                    //controller:'PacksController',
                    abstract:true,
                    views: {
                        '@': {
                            template:'<ui-view/>',
                            controller: 'PacksController',
                            controllerAs: 'packctrl'
                        },
                        'header@': {
                            templateUrl: 'static/vendor/views/packs.html',
                            controller: 'PacksController',
                            controllerAs: 'packctrl'
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state('packs.general',{
                    parent:'packs',
                    url:'/general',
                    views: {
                        '@': {
                            templateUrl:'static/vendor/views/packs.general.html',
                            controller: 'PacksController',
                            controllerAs:'packctrl'
                        }
                    }
                })
```

Html code is :

```
  <div ui-view></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)
Also it seems that this question already has on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400688/ui-router-with-multiple-views-on-an-abstract-parent)

```
<body>
  <div ui-view="filters"></div>
  <div ui-view="tabledata"></div>
  <div ui-view="graph"></div>
</body>
```

the router definition :

```
$stateProvider
  .state('report', {
    views: {
      'filters': { ... templates and/or controllers ... },
      'tabledata': {},
      'graph': {},
    }
  })
```